# why pycharm try to automatically do ssh-add?

Tags: intellij-idea, ssh, pycharm

On ubuntu, after openning pycharm 2019.1.1, every few minutes it will try to ask for password of my ssh id. When I look at the process tree. There is `ssh-add` got spawned. What hell is going on? Why it try to access something without my permission?

This never happens in previous version. I try to disable all ssh plugin and auto sync in git. But same thing keeps happening.

This also happens on other intellij IDEs.

Comment: Do you use the settings repository feature? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html.

Comment: Sounds similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-208989 Try to disable "Mark branches that have incoming/outgoing commits" in "Preferences | Version Control | Git"

Comment: @PavelKarateev Thanks a lot, please provide an answer, then I can accept it.

Comment: @PavelKarateev and very unfortunately there is no global setting for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is caused by a known PyCharm issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-208989

Current workaround is to disable **Mark branches that have incoming/outgoing commits** in **Preferences | Version Control | Git**.